# Getting null as jdbctemplate while testing db with JdbcTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jdbctemplate

I am trying to test the db call with h2 database but jdbc template is turning out to be null.
I have already set the application-testing.properties and set the environment in eclipse as active for this this property.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTest;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
// 

@Sql({ "schema.sql", "test-data.sql" })
@JdbcTest
public class DbTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateRead;

    @Test
    public void testTheDatabase() {
        // PDao paymentDao = new PDao();
        // paymentDao.setJdbcTemplateRead(jdbcTemplateRead);
        // User user = paymentDao.getUser(0l);
        // assertThat(user.getPlatForm()).isEqualTo(5);
    }
}
```

**application-testing.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

**Getting this exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.til.gaana.user.api.service.impl.DbTest.testTheDatabase(DbTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

**Spring boot version**
2.0.4.RELEASE

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
        <scope>test</scope> 
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 1.8.1 junit-platform-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.10</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are, despite the JUnit 5 dependencies, using JUnit 4. So either use a JUnit 5 `@Test` annotation or add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to your class.

Comment: You should remove all the Junit dependencies. And I would also recommend to update to the most recent Spring Boot version

Comment: @M.Deinum        When i try with junit 5 `@ Test` i get same null pointer exception and when i try with `@ RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`  i get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)..............

Comment: So you are using JUnit 4 then and your configuration is borked. Please don't add additional code/errors as comments as those are totally unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum Any help.. how to work it out with junit 5 ?

Comment: For starters use only junit5 dependencies and the fact you have those exclusions (why, those are already part of `spring-boot-starter-test`) and you are messing around with versions. That latter fact makes me wonder if you are messing around with maven even more.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am using ArgumentsAccessor and Mockito.lenient() that's why I had to override the versions.

Comment: You downgraded the versions of mockito and updated the versions of junit. So basically you have non compatible versions, I would suggest using the proper way for the new version of mockito.